# Vuex - Memory Leak/ JS heap size when polling a big chunk of data in every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, vuex, heap-memory

I have a Vue application which is using Vuex for store management. There are multiple store modules I have at the root and every 5 seconds, I pull a big chunk of data and push it to the store state with the help of store mutations.
the problem is every time the state mutates the heap size increases. It keeps on growing till the time the browser is out of memory.

my store looks something like below.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
   moduleA,
   moduleB
  }
})
```

Comment: which browser are you using and have you benchmarked others against each other? I've certainly seen some instances of big vuex jamming up on IE and Edge in the past

Comment: i am checking on chrome and new edge browser. the vuex store state is updated with the new data every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

All Of the entire page state (including the DOM and Javascript/Vuex data) will remain in memory until you do a full page reload in SPAs (which would be the case if you're using vue-router).

In a SPAs, you need to ensure that you drop any references (e.g. set to null) to large objects and arrays when they are no longer needed so that the memory can be freed by the garbage collector.

It is important to delete or free the objects and variables you no longer need before the memory heap is out.